# How to handle nillable in a WSDL file in a SoapUI mock service

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl, soapui

Trying to generate a mock SOAP service, but I get an error ...

```
WSDLException (at /definitions/message[23]/part[1]): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: 
Encountered illegal extension attribute 'nillable'. 
Extension attributes must be in a namespace other than WSDL's
```

which looks to be because of the element ...

```
<part name="ChangesSince" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
```

... certainly if I remove it, SoapUI stops complaining and generates a mock service

But if I then generate WCF clients against the mock service, the date time is a ...

```
private System.DateTime closureDateField;
```

whereas against the real web service they generate as ...

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ClosureDate
```

Is there some way to handle nillable's in SoapUI?